# Python: losing nucleotides from fasta file to dictionary

Tags: python, fasta

I am trying to write a code to extract longest ORF in a fasta file. It is from Coursera Genomics data science course.

the file is a practice file: "dna.example.fasta"

Data is here:https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/genpython/data_sets/dna.example.fasta

Part of my code is below to extract **reading frame 2** (start from the second position of a sequence. eg: seq: ATTGGG, to get reading frame 2: TTGGG):

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
import getopt

o, a = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'h')

opts = dict()
for k,v in o:
        opts[k] = v
        if '-h' in k:
                print "--help\n"

if len(a) < 0:
        print "missing fasta file\n"



f = open(a[0], "r")


seq = dict()
for line in f:

        line = line.strip()

        if line.startswith(">"):
                name = line.split()[0]

                seq[name] = ''

        else:
                seq[name] = seq[name] + line[1:]


k = seq[">gi|142022655|gb|EQ086233.1|323"]
print len(k)
```

The length of this particular sequence should be 4804 bp. Therefore by using this sequence alone I could get the correct answer.
However, with the code, here in the dictionary, this particular sequence becomes only 4736 bp.

I am new to python, so I can not wrap my head around as to where did those 100 bp go?

Thank you,

Xio

Comment: Do you have duplicate names?

Comment: Transcript ids seem unique. There are only 25 sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at your data file

An example of some of the lines:

```
>gi|142022655|gb|EQ086233.1|43 marine metagenome JCVI_SCAF_1096627390048 genomic scaffold, whole genome shotgun sequence
TCGGGCGAAGGCGGCAGCAAGTCGTCCACGCGCAGCGCGGCACCGCGGGCCTCTGCCGTGCGCTGCTTGG
CCATGGCCTCCAGCGCACCGATCGGATCAAAGCCGCTGAAGCCTTCGCGCATCAGGCGGCCATAGTTGGC
```

Notice how the sequences start on the first value of each line.
Your addition line `seq[name] = seq[name] + line[1:]` is adding everything on that line after the first character, excluding the first (Python 2 indicies are zero based). It turns out your missing number of nucleotides is the number of lines it took to make that genome, because you're losing the first character every time.

The revised way is `seq[name] = seq[name] + line` which simply adds the line without losing that first character.

The quickest way to find these kind of debugging errors is to either use a formal debugger, or add a bunch of print statements on your code and test with a small portion of the file -- something that you can see the output of and check for yourself if it's coming out right. A short file with maybe 50 nucleotides instead of 5000 is much easier to evaluate by hand and make sure the code is doing what you want. That's what I did to come up with the answer to the problem in about 5 minutes.

Also for future reference, please mention the version of python you are using before hand. There are quite a few differences between python 2 (The one you're using) and python 3.

I did some additional testing with your code, and if you get any extra characters at the end, they might be whitespace. Make sure you use the `.strip()` method on each line before adding it to your string, which clears whitespace.

Addressing your comment,

To start from the 2nd position on the first line of the sequence only and then use the full lines until the following nucleotide, you can take advantage of the file's linear format and just add one more clause to your if statement, an elif. This will test if we're on the first line of the sequence, and if so, use the characters starting from the second, if we're on any other line, use the whole line.

```
        if line.startswith(">"):
                name = line.split()[0]

                seq[name] = ''

             #If it's the first line in the series, then the dict's value
             # will be an empty string, so this elif means "If we're at the
             # start of the series..."
        elif seq[name] == '':
                seq[name] = seq[name] + line[1:]
        else:
                seq[name] = seq[name]
```

This adaptation will start from the 2nd nucleotide in the genome without losing the first from every line in the rest of the nucleotide.

Comment: Thank you for response! 1) Using line[1:] was to get reading frame 2 as I mentioned in the question. Actually my code works well on reading frame 1, with the same sequence. That's why it had me debugging a whole day to notice the sequence difference in the dictionary 2) Adding `print line[1:]` right after `seq[name] = seq[name] + line[1:]` gave me right length including a count of `\n`. Just the sequence in dictionary length short of 100 bp. 3) I did try `.strip()` no differences so far.

Comment: You say using frame 2 means starting from the second position in the sequence. Is a sequence the entire distance between two metagenomes, or is it every line, or is there a different definition of "sequence"? If it's the distance between two metagenomes, then this is still the same issue. The genome 323 is made up of 69 lines, and you are missing 68 nucleotides. There are 4805 characters between genome 323 and genome 564, so if you start from the second character of the whole sequence, not on every line, then you get 4804 nucleotides.

Comment: I see what you mean now! Because each line of sequence is ended with `\n` and the code will read each line from position 2. That's why I am loosing 68 letters. I should get the whole sequence first than read from position 2 or get rid of new line character first then read from position 2. Thank you!